# .htaccess Magento in root need to get WordPress in subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, magento, subdirectory

I have a Magento install in my root and need to get a WordPress site running in a subdirectory but it seems that it is redirecting back to the root homepage.

Below is the Magento .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>


Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the default Magento .htaccess in the root and the default WP .htaccess in the Wordpress subdirectory.

Comment: Thanks but I a currently using both default files.

The above is the default Magento with the comments stripped out

Comment: Yes I ended up putting the website on another server and linked it via a CNAME

Answer (score 0):

problem will be... if there is no physical file found mage will pass the request to its index.php this can cause trouble when adding a redirecting app below mage... we always used seperate vhost for wordpress and "faked" the subfolder by using proxy redirects to the vhost. Works perfect.

If this is not an option we need some more input... e.g. can you access the loginpage of wordpress by calling domain/worpressdir/wp-admin???

and how are your wordpresspaths are configured in the wp db?

Cheers 
Ben

Comment: Hello Ben, I could indeed access the wp-admin part of the blog and by updating the .htaccess though permlinks solved everything